# Which payment API allows taking payments from a set of customers and paying out to another set of customers?

Tags: payment-gateway, stripe-payments, braintree, payment-processing

Say for instance I have a set of customers that are paying to me on a subscription basis and I have another set of customers who I want to then pay on subscription basis, taking a cut in the middle. Which payment API allows to do that? I know PayPal has masspay but it requires you to have a PayPal account. I want to be able to take payments from direct debit/credit card/debit card and pay to bank transfer/debit card. I'm making all transactions in UK.

I've explored Stripe, Braintree and GoCardless. All of them make it easy to take a payment but nowhere on the site I could find a way to pay to a customer. Am I missing something? Why isn't this easy? Any help/pointers will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why are these other customer's receiving funds / getting paid? That will determine a lot about what APIs you can use

Comment: They are getting paid.

Comment: I should also be worried about money laundering

Comment: I am trying to think what would be the benefit that you provide

Comment: Without going off-topic, think AirBnB and Uber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they're being paid for services that they have performed for the customer, then Stripe and Braintree both offer APIs for Marketplaces. Stripe is called Stripe Connect, and Braintree is called Marketplaces. The key thing to note for these APIs is that you must specify who the person receiving the funds is when you charge the customer. Neither platform supports blanket transferring of funds from your "platform" to each merchant as that falls under "Money Transmission". Instead, you'll end up creating accounts for each merchant (and you'll be required to ask for information like address, tax id, bank account info etc), and the charge from the customer goes directly to their account (with you potentially taking a cut from the transaction).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I did notice stripe connect and braintree marketplace but wasn't sure if they were available outside of US (my use being in UK). Braintree seems a bit expensive with their 2.9% cut and I'm unsure if Stripe Connect is available outside US. Do you know if GoCardless have a marketplace option?

Comment: Braintree marketplace is US only, Stripe Connect is available for marketplaces outside the US, but you'd have to use "Standalone Account" (basically each seller needs a full stripe account), or you'd have to contact support about access to a managed accounts beta for that country. GoCardless appears to have a "whitelabel" api you need to contact them about https://developer.gocardless.com/pro/2015-07-06/#creditors-create-a-creditor